# Going from swagger json/yaml to Java annotations

Tags: json, yaml, swagger

I have swagger yaml files. I want to add Java swagger annotations instead. Is there any easy way to generate java swagger annotations from existing yaml files (there is an easy way to go from java annotations to swagger json, but what about the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [swagger.io](http://editor2.swagger.io/#!/) page, past your yaml definition file and clic on Server Generate menu and choose one of the Java framework that yo use.